# How to avoid redundancy in database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, redundancy

I created an user registration & Log in app. I have done the following.

***MainActivity.java***

```
 si=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    su=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    si.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
    su.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent2=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Signup.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    });
```

***Signup.java***

```
databaseAdapter=new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    databaseAdapter=databaseAdapter.open();

    un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    cnfpwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    signu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    signu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Uname=un.getText().toString();
            String passw=pwd.getText().toString();
            String cnfpassw=cnfpwd.getText().toString();

            if (Uname.equals("")||passw.equals("")||cnfpassw.equals("")){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Fill all the Fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                show("Error","Please fill all the fields");
                return;
            }

            if(!passw.equals(cnfpassw)){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password does not match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                show("Error","Password does not match");
                pwd.setText("");
                cnfpwd.setText("");
                return;
            } else {
                databaseAdapter.insertEntry(Uname,passw);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Account Created Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                show("Success", "Account Created Successfully");
                //finish();
                un.setText("");
                pwd.setText("");
                cnfpwd.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void show(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Signup.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
```

***Login.java***

```
   databaseAdapter=new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    databaseAdapter=databaseAdapter.open();

    UN=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    PWD=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    si=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    si.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String UserName=UN.getText().toString();
            String Password=PWD.getText().toString();

            String storedPassword=databaseAdapter.getSingleEntry(UserName);
            //String storesUserName=databaseAdapter.getUserName(Password);

            if (UserName.equals("")||Password.equals("")){
                show("Error","Please fill all Fields");
                return;
            }
            if (Password.equals(storedPassword)){
                //Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                show("Success","Login Successful");
                String storedUserName=databaseAdapter.getUserDetails(Password);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),storedUserName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("number",storedUserName);
                Intent intent2=new Intent(Login.this,Inbox.class);
                intent2.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent2);
            } else {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username or Password is incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                show("Error","Username or Password is incorrect");
                UN.setText("");
                PWD.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void show(String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}
```

Now i can Signup and Log in from database. But the `Database` allows redundancy. i.e., it allows the same value any number of times. I want to avoid that in order to register unique Usernames. Any Solutions?

Comment: check if the value exist before inserting it into the database

Comment: what is the condition used to check that? please. i don't know.

Comment: That's not redundancy but uniqueness.

Comment: Add a UNIQUE constraint to your username+password columns combination

Answer (score 0):

I am here only giving you an idea it is the sample of the code i am using in my project you can change it your way, here is how you can see if the data is already there. This method will return true if the data with the title you are passing is in database.

```
String SELECT_ALL_BY_TITLE = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_TITLE + "=? ;";

 public boolean ifAlreadyExists(String title) {

    if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(SELECT_ALL_BY_TITLE, new String[] { title});
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        } else {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Database not open");
    return false;
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean isUserExists(String username) {
    boolean isdataAvail = false;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;

        String query = "SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE user_name = "+ username;
        db = YourDbHelper.getInstance().getReadableDatabase();
        if(db.isOpen())
        {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            try {
                if( cursor.getCount() > 0){
                    isdataAvail = true;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                if (db != null) {
                    if (db.isOpen()) {
                        db.close();
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return isdataAvail;
}
```

if is data available this methods returns **true** then there is a record found in DB with the given name.